# Is there a specific way to simulate porous structures?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus, porous-medium

I tried to simulate an axial compression test for a **lattice** (porous) structure but It takes too much time and it doesn't give me the right answer (when I compare with experimental results). So, I was wondering if there are another methods to simulate these kind of structures. I have heared about **homogenization** method but I really don't know if it works or not. Can you please help me with this? I really need to be guided so please help me if you know anything about this.
Thank you in advance
P.S My lattice structure is a gyroid based structure

Comment: I think you need to better define your test method and the goal for the test, also the type of structure you are performing the test - engineering structure, or atomic structure.

Comment: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsta.2005.1678#d16288025e1 .. treating lattice structures as bulk materials

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as a beam and subject it to a load, P at the center. By measuring its deflection you could approximately find its young modulus, I.

In order to make it easy to measure the deflection, you should pick a shallow beam like slab, say a beam with length= 50 times its height, say:

- L= length= 100cm
- h= height = 2cm
- B= width= 4cm
  $$I= \frac{Bh^3}{12}$$
  and the deflection will be
  $$\delta=\frac{PL^3}{48EI}$$

$$E=\frac{PL^3}{ (48I)\delta}=\frac{12PL^3}{48Bh^3\delta}=\frac{PL^3}{4Bh^3\delta}$$

Answer (score 0):

there is a material behavior in AbaqusCAE namely `porous elasticity`, it can describe porous elastic behavior at the cost of extra paramaters.